# Optimal Method to Minify an XML in C# 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, json, linq-to-xml

Coding Platform: ASP.NET C#

I have an XML like this.

```
<Items>
    <Map id="35">
        <Terrains>
            <Item id="1" row="0" column="0"/>
            <Item id="1" row="0" column="1"/>
            <Item id="1" row="0" column="2"/>
            <Item id="1" row="0" column="3"/>
            <Item id="1" row="0" column="4"/>
        </Terrains>
    </Map>
</Items>
```

I would like to minify this to

```
<Its>
    <Map id="30">
        <Te>
            <It id="1" r="0" c="0"/>
            <It id="1" r="0" c="1"/>
            <It id="1" r="0" c="2"/>
            <It id="1" r="0" c="3"/>
            <It id="1" r="0" c="4"/>
        </Te>
    </Map>
</Its>
```

Then I am converting this to JSON using [James Newton-King's JSON Converter](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx).
The idea is to minify the xml data to the maximum as it contains tens of thousands of lines.

My questions are

1. What is the optimal method to minify the xml as mentioned above?
2. Now its done like XML-MinifyXML-Convert to JSON. Can I do it in two steps?(XML-Minify while converting to JSON)
3. Is James Newton-King's JSON converter a bit overkill for this simple conversion?

Please provide code snippets also if possible.

Comment: -1: This is not mimifying the XML because it changes the semantics (JavaScript minifying might change the names of locals, but they are not used outside those functions). Minifying XML would be about avoiding repeating long namespace tags, eliminating non-significant whitespace and so forth.

Comment: @Richard: What should i call it then? Packing?

Comment: "using shorter identifiers", any consumer of the XML needs to be able to extract the data, so its going to need to know the node names. Thus the transform will be fixed.

Comment: XML documents should be human-legible and reasonably clear,  Terseness in XML markup is of minimal importance

Comment: @Caspar: I disagree that terseness is *always* of minimal importance.  It is a great interchange format, but sometimes the volume of data to be interchanged is significant compared to the processing power of the systems involved.

Comment: @CasparKleijne: It was for an MMO. reducing size was super important

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect GZIP (via GZipStream, or simply via IIS, noting that you need to enable dynamic compression for the json mime-type) would be both simpler and smaller, but if you are using serializarion, simply adding some [XmlElement(...)] / [XmlAttribute(...)] should do it. Of course, if size is your concern, can I also suggest something like protobuf-net, which gives an extremely dense binary output.

If you aren't using serialisation, then this looks an ideal fit for some "xslt":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/Items">
    <Its><xsl:apply-templates/></Its>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/Items/Map/Terrains">
    <Te><xsl:apply-templates/></Te>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/Items/Map/Terrains/Item">
    <It id="{@id}" r="{@row}" c="{@column}"><xsl:apply-templates select="*"/></It>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(with C#:)

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load("Condense.xslt"); // cache and re-use this object; don't Load each time
xslt.Transform("Data.xml", "Smaller.xml");

 Console.WriteLine("{0} vs {1}",
    new FileInfo("Data.xml").Length,
    new FileInfo("Smaller.xml").Length);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am getting this XML as input from an SWF and .NET part is to minify(or rather pack) the xml n then convert to json so that size is much smaller. I am saving the JSON at another location for another SWF to access it.

Comment: @naveen - the xslt route, then (example added)

Comment: @naveen well you could use LINQ-XML, but xslt is handy (designed for) transforming XML.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. I really was mentioning that.